# Passing dynamic element id to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this code in my .gsp
this image link trigger event on click through jquery function. the problem is i want to pass the dynamic id (`id="deleteSupp_${supplementary.id}"` ) to the jquery function so it can trigger the event handler when the image link is clicked.

```
 <div  class="deleteSupplementary" data-supplementary=["${supplementary.id}","${supplementary.sth?.id}"]>
    <a href="#" >
       <r:img  id="deleteSupp_${supplementary.id}"  class="icon float-right" uri="/img/app-icon-delete.gif"  title="delete"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery function

```
function showConfirmationPanel(){

    $("#deleteSupp_${supplementary.id}").live('click',function (event){

        event.preventDefault();
        $("#someform").show();
    });

}
```

Comment: is `${supplementary.id}` some sort of server side template syntax?

Comment: I assume you're using an old version of jQuery because `live` has been deprecated for some time.

Comment: Inside the function you can access the element and get the information you need from it. $(this) gives a reference to the element as a jQuery element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function showConfirmationPanel()    
{
    $('img[id^="deleteSupp_"').on   
    (
        'click',                    
        function (event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            // Get the supplementary id
            var sSuppId = $(this).closest(".deleteSupplementary")
                                 .data("supplementary")[0];    

            $("#someform").show();
        }
    );
}
```